# Web2Py - rendering AJAX response as HTML table

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, web2py

I am new to Web2Py, Python stack. I have a simple requirement to implement. I need to pass some data from a UI form to a Controller action for processing. After processing the data that action returns a response back to the view which I need to render as an HTML table on the same view. I am using AJAX for this purpose.

I am able to get the response back to the view but don't know how to iterate over the elements of that response to render as an HTML table. When I run the below code all it does is replace the entire target DIV with the response content.

I know it's pretty straightforward to this in Java, Grails, PHP, etc. But, I am struggling to find a way to that in Web2Py.

I have the following snippets in my code:
index.html:

```
<script>
jQuery('#input_form').submit(function() {
    ajax('{{=URL('process_form')}}',
            ['input_var1','input_var2','input_var3','input_var4'], 'results_div');
    return false;
});
```

```
<div id="results_div">
    <form>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="records_table" class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th>Col Head 1</th>
                    <th>Col Head 2</th>
                    <th>Col Head 3</th>
                    <th>Col Head 4</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Col Content 11</td>
                    <td>Col Content 12</td>
                    <td>Col Content 13</td>
                    <td>Col Content 14</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Col Content 21</td>
                    <td>Col Content 22</td>
                    <td>Col Content 23</td>
                    <td>Col Content 24</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

default.py

```
def process_form():
    results = request.vars
    return DIV(results)
```

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the Ajax function expects to receive HTML, which it will place inside of the element whose id is passed in. So, the simplest approach is to have your `process_form` function return the full HTML of the table, so the content of the `results_div` div will be replaced with the new table. You can build the HTML in Python using the web2py HTML helpers, or you can use a template, as with any other controller action. For example:

```
def process_form():
    inputs = ['input1', 'input2', 'input3']
    html = DIV(TABLE(THEAD(TR(TH('Column 1'), TH('Column 2'), TH('Column 3')),
                           _class='test', _id=0),
                     TR([request.vars[input] for input in inputs]),
                     _id='records_table', _class='table table-bordered'),
               _class='table-responsive')
    return html
```

Alternatively, you could have the `process_form` function return JSON data. In that case, you can make the third argument to `ajax()` a Javascript function, and the returned JSON data will be passed to that function. The function could then populate the existing table with the new data.

Comment: Thanks Anthony, I would like to take the first approach you mentioned regarding: "You can build the HTML in Python using the web2py HTML helpers, or you can use a template, as with any other controller action". Could you kindly share a code example of building the HTML in Python using Web2Py HTML helpers?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot Anthony for pointing me in the right direction. It's making much more sense now. However, I am little confused about the way you've generated the TABLE. I am not able to understand the semantics of syntax that you used in `html = DIV(TABLE(TR([request.vars[input] for input in inputs]),
                     _id='records_table', _class='table table-bordered'),
               _class='table-responsive')`. I have been trying to compare this with the syntax shown at: [link](http://www.web2py.com/book/default/chapter/05#TABLE--TR--TD) i.e. `TABLE(*[TR(*rows) for rows in table])`

Comment: Also could you guide regarding adding a header row as well on top of the table? How would I add this kind of statement `THEAD(TR(TH('<hello>')), _class='test', _id=0)`, within the same Table generation HTML?

Comment: `TR` can either take a set of positional arguments (each of which will be considered a component of the `TR` and therefore wrapped in a `TD`), or it can take a list as a single positional argument, and it will treat each item in the list as a component (again wrapping in a `TD`). So, if you have a list, you can do either `TR(the_list)` or `TR(*the_list)`. The latter simply acts as if you passed each list item as a separate positional argument (the `*` syntax is Python argument unpacking syntax -- not specific to `TR` or web2py).

Comment: Regarding the table head, `TABLE` is like any other helper and can take as many components as you would like as positional arguments, so just insert your `THEAD` object before the `TR` object (note, you should make sure the `THEAD` has the correct number of columns). I edited the example to show this.

Comment: If you have more questions about using the HTML helpers, you might want to open additional questions rather than try to hash this out in the comments.