# Web2Py - using starred expression for rendering HTML table

Tags: python, html, web2py

This question is an extension of: [Web2Py - rendering AJAX response as HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31576302/web2py-rendering-ajax-response-as-html-table)

Basically, I come up with a dynamic list of response rows that I need to display on the UI as an HTML table.

Essentially the code looks like this,

```
response_results = []

row_one = ['1', 'Col 11', 'Col 12', 'Col 13']
response_results.append(row_one)

row_two = ['2', 'Col 21', 'Col 22', 'Col 23']
response_results.append(row_two)

html = DIV(TABLE(THEAD(TR(TH('Row #'), TH('Col 1'), TH('Col 2'), TH('Col 3')), 
                       _id=0), TR([*response for response in response_results]),
                 _id='records_table', _class='table table-bordered'),
           _class='table-responsive')
return html
```

When I use this kind of code: `TR([request.vars[input] for input in inputs])` or `TR(*the_list)`, it works fine.

However, I have come up with a need to use a hybrid of these two i.e. `TR([*response for response in response_results])`. But, it fails giving an error message:

> "Python version 2.7 does not support this syntax. Starred expressions are not allowed as assignment targets in Python 2."

When I run this code instead i.e. without a '*': `TR([response for response in response_results])` it runs fine but puts all the columns of my row together in the first column of the generated HTML table, leaving all other columns blank.

Can someone kindly help me resolve this issue and guide on how can I achieve the required result of displaying each column of the rows at their proper spots in the generated HTML table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate a `TR` for each item in `response_results`, which means you need a list of `TR` elements with which you can then use Python argument expansion (i.e., the `*` syntax) to treat each `TR` as a positional argument to `TABLE`.

```
html = DIV(TABLE(THEAD(TR(TH('Row #'), TH('Col 1'), TH('Col 2'), TH('Col 3')), _id=0),
                 *[TR(response) for response in response_results],
                 _id='records_table', _class='table table-bordered'),
           _class='table-responsive')
```

Note, because each `response` is itself a list, you could also use argument expansion *within* the `TR`:

```
*[TR(*response) for response in response_results]
```

But that is not necessary, as `TR` optionally takes a list, converting each item in the list into a table cell.

Another option is to make `response_results` a list of `TR` elements, starting with the `THEAD` element, and then just pass that list to `TABLE`:

```
response_results = [THEAD(TR(TH('Row #'), TH('Col 1'), TH('Col 2'), TH('Col 3')), _id=0)]

row_one = ['1', 'Col 11', 'Col 12', 'Col 13']
response_results.append(TR(row_one))

row_two = ['2', 'Col 21', 'Col 22', 'Col 23']
response_results.append(TR(row_two))

html = DIV(TABLE(response_results, _id='records_table', _class='table table-bordered'),
           _class='table-responsive')
```

Again, you could do `TABLE(*response_results, ...)`, but the `*` is not necessary, as `TABLE` can take a list of row elements.

Comment: Beautiful Solutions! Anthony I guess you are the best guide for Web2Py on Stack Overflow :-)